# Changing the boot order in grub to have windows boot by default

Tags: grub

When my computer boots up I get the grub menu with Elementary Odin as the first item. If I do nothing it boots to Odin of course.

I would like to have windows boot by default.

I have tried grub-customizer but it doesn't change the boot order even after moving windows to the top above Elementary Odin and saving the changes.

Ideas?

Rex

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/110738/1222991), which outlines how to do this. Grub Customizer has its quirks at times, but nothing beats a Terminal when it comes time to do some boot-level editing. Just remember to use `sudo update-grub` when finished, or your settings will not be applied 

Comment: Thanks for the information. I used Grub-Customizer and got it to do as I wanted.